# which has better pseudocode? IDA or Ghidra

Tags: ida, disassembly, c, ghidra

I would like to know which of the two has a better pseudo code generator in C, IDA or Ghidra, if possible, point out the strengths and low points of each one.

Comment: that's a pretty subjective and situational question. you might want to narrow what you're looking for.  

Generally though I'd say ghidra beats IDA in that it has decompiler for each processor if it implements the SLEIGH/pcode correctly.  On the other hand IDA's decompiler is very optimized for the architecture/system it does support.